# JSP/JSTL how to improve speed of using c:forech

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I've started looking at a page in a web application that has some performance issues. It's a Spring MVC app using JSP.
There's a section that is built as follows:

```
 <c:forEach items="${people}" var="person">
     //A number of <form:input>s bound to "person" in here
 </c:foreach>
```

This seems to render quite slowly as the number of "people" gets large. The number of iterations doesn't even have to be that high for it to be slow. I can see the page loading each block of inputs one by one.

I was playing around trying to determine what the bottleneck is and I think it seems that it's just the nature of the for loop that's slow.

If I do the following:

```
<div with some style><input></div>
//Copy this 8000 times
```

The page renders quite fast.
But the following:

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="1" end="8000">
<div with some style><input></div>
</c:foreach>
```

renders slowly.

I guess I'm a bit puzzled since since it seems like it's sending each iteration to the client to render rather than building the HTML up and then sending all at once? (Maybe I have that wrong?)

Is there a way to make this load faster? Would setting some precompiling for the JSP be faster (though I'm not sure how since ${people} is determined at runtime)?

Comment: don't use jsps, lazy load from an ajx call

Comment: world has moved on from jsp and specially jstl.

Comment: Yeah I definitely get that client side frameworks are the way to go these days (unfortunately not an option at this time). But people must have done stuff like this with JSP/JSTL rendering. I figure something must be wrong as if I'm displaying only 6-10 'people' worth of fields the page renders very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

You use paging. all programming to use lazy loading. 
lazy loading is a design pattern commonly used in computer programming to defer initialization of an object until the point at which it is needed. It can contribute to efficiency in the program's operation if properly and appropriately used. The opposite of lazy loading is eager loading.